# Arcgis Server Write properties of all services to a CSV file

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-server

I have 36 Services running on ArcGIS Server and would like export all properties for each service in a csv file. I managed to write a code by the help of ESRI Helpdesk http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0154000005wt000000 adding the properties "maxImageHeight" and "maxImageWidth" to the request. However if I run the code it starts to work, writes properties of the first 22 services, but than it stopps suddenly and returns

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\SCRIPTS\Py-scripts\ArcPy\AGS - ArcPy\AGS_service_report_as_csv2.py", line 436, in 
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "D:\SCRIPTS\Py-scripts\ArcPy\AGS - ArcPy\AGS_service_report_as_csv2.py", line 201, in main
    + "NA" + "\n"
KeyError: 'maxImageHeight'

It's odd because it delivered allready the "maxImageHeight" property for the first services.

Code:

```
# Reads the following properties from services and writes them to a comma-delimited file:
#  ServiceName, Folder, Type, Status, Min Instances, Max Instances, Max Wainting Time,Max Startup Time,Max Idle Time,Max Usage Time, KML,
#  WMS, WFS, WCS, Max Records, Cluster, Cache Directory, Jobs Directory, Output Directory

# For HTTP calls
import httplib, urllib, json

# For system tools
import sys

# For reading passwords without echoing
import getpass

def main(argv=None):

    # Ask for admin/publisher user name and password
    username = raw_input("Enter user name: ")
    password = getpass.getpass("Enter password: ")

    # Ask for server name & port
    serverName = raw_input("Enter server name: ")
    serverPort = 6080

    # Get the location and the name of the file to be created
    resultFile = raw_input("Output File (get the location and the name of the file to be created): ")

    # Get a token
    token = getToken(username, password, serverName, serverPort)

    # Get the root info
    serverURL = "/arcgis/admin/services/"
    #serverURL = "/arcgis/manager/services/"

    # This request only needs the token and the response formatting parameter
    params = urllib.urlencode({'token': token, 'f': 'json'})

    headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept": "text/plain"}

    # Connect to URL and post parameters
    httpConn = httplib.HTTPConnection(serverName, serverPort)
    httpConn.request("POST", serverURL, params, headers)

    # Read response
    response = httpConn.getresponse()
    if (response.status != 200):
        httpConn.close()
        print "Could not read folder information."
        return
    else:
        data = response.read()

        # Check that data returned is not an error object
        if not assertJsonSuccess(data):
            print "Error when reading server information. " + str(data)
            return
        else:
            print "Processed server information successfully. Now processing folders..."

        # Deserialize response into Python object
        dataObj = json.loads(data)
        httpConn.close()

        #Store the Folders in a list to loop on
        folders = dataObj["folders"]

        #Remove the System and Utilities folders
        folders.remove("System")
        #folders.remove("Utilities")

        #Add an entry for the root folder
        folders.append("")

        #Create the summary file of services
        serviceResultFile = open(resultFile,'w')
        #serviceResultFile.write("ServiceName,Folder,Type,Status,Min Instances,Max Instances,FeatureService,kml,wms,Max Records,Cluster,Cache Directory,Jobs Directory,Output Directory" + "\n")
        serviceResultFile.write("\
            ServiceName,\
            Folder,\
            Type,\
            MaxImageHeight,\
            MaxImageWidth,\
            Status,\
            Min Instances,\
            Max Instances,\
            Max Wainting Time,\
            Max Startup Time,\
            Max Idle Time,\
            Max Usage Time,\
            FeatureService,\
            kml,\
            wms,\
            wfs,\
            wcs,\
            Max Records,\
            Cluster,\
            Cache Directory,\
            Jobs Directory,\
            Output Directory" + "\n")

        #Loop on the found folders and discover the services and write the service information
        for folder in folders:

            # Determine if the loop is working on the root folder or not
            if folder != "":
                folder += "/"

            # Build the URL for the current folder
            folderURL = "/arcgis/admin/services/" + folder
            params = urllib.urlencode({'token': token, 'f': 'json'})
            headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept": "text/plain"}

            # Connect to URL and post parameters
            httpConn = httplib.HTTPConnection(serverName, serverPort)
            httpConn.request("POST", folderURL, params, headers)

            # Read response
            response = httpConn.getresponse()
            if (response.status != 200):
                httpConn.close()
                print "Could not read folder information."
                return
            else:
                data = response.read()

                # Check that data returned is not an error object
                if not assertJsonSuccess(data):
                    print "Error when reading folder information. " + str(data)
                else:
                    print "Processed folder information successfully. Now processing services..."

                # Deserialize response into Python object
                dataObj = json.loads(data)
                httpConn.close()

                # Loop through each service in the folder
                for item in dataObj['services']:

                    if item["type"] == "GeometryServer":# and folder == "":
                        # Build the Service URL
                        if folder:
                            sUrl = "/arcgis/admin/services/%s%s.%s" %(folder,item["serviceName"], item["type"])
                            statusUrl = "/arcgis/admin/services/%s%s.%s/status" %(folder,item["serviceName"], item["type"])
                        else:
                            sUrl = "/arcgis/admin/services/%s.%s" %(item["serviceName"], item["type"])
                            statusUrl = "/arcgis/admin/services/%s.%s/status" %(item["serviceName"], item["type"])



                        httpConn.request("POST", sUrl, params, headers)

                        # Get the response
                        servResponse = httpConn.getresponse()
                        readData = servResponse.read()
                        jsonOBJ = json.loads(readData)

                        # Build the Service URL to test the running status


                        # Submit the request to the server
                        httpConn.request("POST", statusUrl, params, headers)
                        servStatusResponse = httpConn.getresponse()

                        # Obtain the data from the response
                        readData = servStatusResponse.read()
                        jsonOBJStatus = json.loads(readData)

                        # Build the line to write to the output file

                        ln = str(jsonOBJ["serviceName"]) + ","\
                        + folder + ","\
                        + str(item["type"]) + ","\
                        + str(jsonOBJ["properties"]["maxImageHeight"]) + ","\
                        + str(jsonOBJ["properties"]["maxImageWidth"]) + ","\
                        + jsonOBJStatus['realTimeState'] + ","\
                        + str(jsonOBJ["minInstancesPerNode"]) + ","\
                        + str(jsonOBJ["maxInstancesPerNode"]) + ","\
                        + str(jsonOBJ["maxWaitTime"]) + ","\
                        + str(jsonOBJ["maxStartupTime"]) + ","\
                        + str(jsonOBJ["maxIdleTime"]) + ","\
                        + str(jsonOBJ["maxUsageTime"]) + ","\
                        + "NA" + ","\
                        + "NA" + ","\
                        + "NA" + ","\
                        + "NA" + ","\
                        + "NA" + ","\
                        + "NA" + ","\
                        + str(jsonOBJ["clusterName"]) + ","\
                        + "NA" + ","\
                        + "NA" + ","\
                        + "NA" + "\n"

                        # Write the results to the file
                        serviceResultFile.write(ln)

                        httpConn.close()

                    elif item["type"] == "SearchServer":# and folder == "":
                        if folder:
                            sUrl = "/arcgis/admin/services/%s%s.%s" %(folder,item["serviceName"], item["type"])
                            statusUrl = "/arcgis/admin/services/%s%s.%s/status" %(folder,item["serviceName"], item["type"])
                        else:
                            sUrl = "/arcgis/admin/services/%s.%s" %(item["serviceName"], item["type"])
                            statusUrl = "/arcgis/admin/services/%s.%s/status" %(item["serviceName"], item["type"])


                        httpConn.request("POST", sUrl, params, headers)

                        # Get the response
                        servResponse = httpConn.getresponse()
                        readData = servResponse.read()
                        jsonOBJ = json.loads(readData)


                        # Submit the request to the server
                        httpConn.request("POST", statusUrl, params, headers)

                        # Get the response
                        servStatusResponse = httpConn.getresponse()
                        readData = servStatusResponse.read()
                        jsonOBJStatus = json.loads(readData)

                        # Build the line to write to the output file

                        ln = str(jsonOBJ["serviceName"]) + ","\
                        + folder + ","\
                        + str(item["type"]) + ","\
                        + str(jsonOBJ["properties"]["maxImageHeight"]) + ","\
                        + str(jsonOBJ["properties"]["maxImageWidth"]) + ","\
                        + jsonOBJStatus['realTimeState'] + ","\
                        + str(jsonOBJ["minInstancesPerNode"]) + ","\
                        + str(jsonOBJ["maxInstancesPerNode"]) + ","\
                        + str(jsonOBJ["maxWaitTime"]) + ","\
                        + str(jsonOBJ["maxStartupTime"]) + ","\
                        + str(jsonOBJ["maxIdleTime"]) + ","\
                        + str(jsonOBJ["maxUsageTime"]) + ","\
                        + "NA" + ","\
                        + "NA" + ","\
                        + "NA" + ","\
                        + "NA" + ","\
                        + "NA" + ","\
                        + "NA" + ","\
                        + str(jsonOBJ["clusterName"]) + ","\
                        + "NA" + ","\
                        + "NA" + ","\
                        + "NA" + "\n"

                        # Write the results to the file
                        serviceResultFile.write(ln)

                        httpConn.close()

#####MapServer########################################

                    elif item["type"] == "MapServer":

                        # Build the Service URL
                        if folder:
                            sUrl = "/arcgis/admin/services/%s%s.%s" %(folder,item["serviceName"], item["type"])
                        else:
                            sUrl = "/arcgis/admin/services/%s.%s" %(item["serviceName"], item["type"])

                        # Submit the request to the server
                        httpConn.request("POST", sUrl, params, headers)

                        # Get the response
                        servResponse = httpConn.getresponse()
                        readData = servResponse.read()
                        jsonOBJ = json.loads(readData)

                        # Build the Service URL to test the running status
                        if folder:
                            statusUrl = "/arcgis/admin/services/%s%s.%s/status" %(folder,item["serviceName"], item["type"])
                        else:
                            statusUrl = "/arcgis/admin/services/%s.%s/status" %(item["serviceName"], item["type"])

                        # Submit the request to the server
                        httpConn.request("POST", statusUrl, params, headers)

                        # Get the response
                        servStatusResponse = httpConn.getresponse()
                        readData = servStatusResponse.read()
                        jsonOBJStatus = json.loads(readData)

                        # Check for Map Cache
                        isCached = jsonOBJ["properties"]["isCached"]
                        if isCached == "true":
                            cacheDir = str(jsonOBJ["properties"]["cacheDir"])
                        else:
                            cacheDir = jsonOBJ["properties"]["isCached"]

                        if len(jsonOBJ["extensions"]) == 0:
                            # Build the line to write to the output file
                            ln = str(jsonOBJ["serviceName"]) + ","\
                            + folder + ","\
                            + str(item["type"]) + ","\
                            + str(jsonOBJ["properties"]["maxImageHeight"]) + ","\
                            + str(jsonOBJ["properties"]["maxImageWidth"]) + ","\
                            + jsonOBJStatus['realTimeState'] + ","\
                            + str(jsonOBJ["minInstancesPerNode"]) + ","\
                            + str(jsonOBJ["maxInstancesPerNode"]) + ","\
                            + "FeatServHolder" + ","\
                            + "Disabled" + ","\
                            + "Disabled" +","\
                            + str(jsonOBJ["properties"]["maxRecordCount"]) + ","\
                            + str(jsonOBJ["clusterName"]) + ","\
                            + cacheDir + ","\
                            + "NA" + ","\
                            + str(jsonOBJ["properties"]["outputDir"]) + "\n"
                        else:
                            # Extract the KML properties from the response
                            kmlProps = [mapKML for mapKML in jsonOBJ["extensions"] if mapKML["typeName"] == 'KmlServer']#.items()[0][1] == 'KmlServer']

                            # Extract the WMS properties from the response
                            wmsProps = [mapWMS for mapWMS in jsonOBJ["extensions"] if mapWMS["typeName"] == 'WMSServer']#.items()[0][1] == 'WMSServer']

                              Extract the WFS properties from the response
                            wfsProps = [mapWFS for mapWFS in jsonOBJ["extensions"] if mapWFS["typeName"] == 'WFSServer']#.items()[0][1] == 'WFSServer']

                             Extract the WCS properties from the response
                            wcsProps = [mapWCS for mapWCS in jsonOBJ["extensions"] if mapWCS["typeName"] == 'WCSServer']#.items()[0][1] == 'WCSServer']

                            # Extract the FeatureService properties from the response
                            featServProps = [featServ for featServ in jsonOBJ["extensions"] if featServ["typeName"] == 'FeatureServer']#.items()[0][1] == 'FeatureServer']

                            if len(featServProps) > 0:
                                featureStatus = str(featServProps[0]["enabled"])
                            else:
                                featureStatus = "NA"

                            if len(kmlProps) > 0:
                                kmlStatus = str(kmlProps[0]["enabled"])
                            else:
                                kmlStatus = "NA"

                            if len(wmsProps) > 0:
                                wmsStatus = str(wmsProps[0]["enabled"])
                            else:
                                wmsStatus = "NA"
#MZ#
                            if len(wfsProps) > 0:
                                wfsStatus = str(wfsProps[0]["enabled"])
                            else:
                                wfsStatus = "NA"
#MZ#
                            if len(wcsProps) > 0:
                                wcsStatus = str(wcsProps[0]["enabled"])
                            else:
                                wcsStatus = "NA"

                         ln = str(jsonOBJ["serviceName"]) + ","\
                            + folder + ","\
                            + str(item["type"]) + ","\
                            + str(jsonOBJ["properties"]["maxImageHeight"]) + ","\
                            + str(jsonOBJ["properties"]["maxImageWidth"]) + ","\
                            + jsonOBJStatus['realTimeState'] + ","\
                            + str(jsonOBJ["minInstancesPerNode"]) + ","\
                            + str(jsonOBJ["maxInstancesPerNode"]) + ","\
                            + str(jsonOBJ["maxWaitTime"]) + ","\
                            + str(jsonOBJ["maxStartupTime"]) + ","\
                            + str(jsonOBJ["maxIdleTime"]) + ","\
                            + str(jsonOBJ["maxUsageTime"]) + ","\
                            + featureStatus + ","\
                            + kmlStatus + ","\
                            + wmsStatus + ","\
                            + wfsStatus + ","\
                            + wcsStatus + ","\
                            + str(jsonOBJ["properties"]["maxRecordCount"]) + ","\
                            + str(jsonOBJ["clusterName"]) + ","\
                            + cacheDir + "," + "NA" + ","\
                            + str(jsonOBJ["properties"]["outputDir"]) + "\n"

                        # Write the results to the file
                        serviceResultFile.write(ln)

                    else:
                        # Close the connection to the current service
                        httpConn.close()

        # Close the file
        serviceResultFile.close()

def getToken(username, password, serverName, serverPort):
    # Token URL is typically http://server[:port]/arcgis/admin/generateToken
    tokenURL = "/arcgis/admin/generateToken"

    params = urllib.urlencode({'username': username, 'password': password, 'client': 'requestip', 'f': 'json'})

    headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept": "text/plain"}

    # Connect to URL and post parameters
    httpConn = httplib.HTTPConnection(serverName, serverPort)
    httpConn.request("POST", tokenURL, params, headers)

    # Read response
    response = httpConn.getresponse()
    if (response.status != 200):
        httpConn.close()
        print "Error while fetching tokens from admin URL. Please check the URL and try again."
        return
    else:
        data = response.read()
        httpConn.close()

        # Check that data returned is not an error object
        if not assertJsonSuccess(data):
            return

        # Extract the token from it
        token = json.loads(data)
        return token['token']


# A function that checks that the input JSON object
#  is not an error object.
def assertJsonSuccess(data):
    obj = json.loads(data)
    if 'status' in obj and obj['status'] == "error":
        print "Error: JSON object returns an error. " + str(obj)
        return False
    else:
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))`
```

Comment: In my experience not all services have the same properties. Maybe a try-except statement to catch your KeyError would solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get past the error by adding bufsize

```
#Create the summary file of services
bufsize = 0
serviceResultFile = open(resultFile,'w',bufsize)
```

Now it's complaining about how to handle the end of the file.  Still working on this bit

```
sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
File "D:/Cognos_Testing/Esri/python/get_mapsrv_Stats.py", line 378,    in main
+ str(jsonOBJ["properties"]["outputDir"]) + "\n"
KeyError: 'maxImageHeight'
```